# Ayuda con inserción de datos en MySQL (XAMPP)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

tengo problemas en la inserción de documentos pdf en mi base de datos, en una computadora si funciona, sin embargo al pasar el proyecto a otra computadora deja de funcionar, tengo exactamente lo mismo y no funciona. La conexión a la base si la efectúa pero la inserción de los archivos no, aqui dejo el código que utilizo para la inserción de documentos.

```
include_once 'conectar.php';
if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$destino = "pdf/" . $nombre;
if ($nombre != "") {
    if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
        $titulo= $_POST['titulo'];
        $descri= $_POST['descripcion'];
        $db=new Conect_MySql();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_documentos(titulo,descripcion,tamanio,tipo,nombre_archivo) VALUES('$titulo','$descripcion','$tamanio','$tipo','$nombre')";
        $query = $db->execute($sql);
        if($query){
            echo "Se guardo correctamente";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
}}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Hola, coloca el mensaje de error ya que por lo que comentas es un problema en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, mira es que no manda ningún mensaje de error, simplemente no inserta el archivo en la base, o sea, no hace nada, pero a la hora de ver los archivos que tengo guardados en la base de datos, si me permite verlos, entonces no es la conexión de la base, si no la inserción pero no se en si a que se deba, :(

Comment: Revisa que en efecto esté llegando a ese punto la ejecución, luego del if($query){} coloca var_dump($query) a ver que te muestra

Comment: No deberías usar `execute`, porque no estás preparando consulta. Cambia esto: `$query = $db->execute($sql);` por esto: **`$query = $db->query($sql);`** Y, también imprime el mensaje de error propio de la conexión, cambiando esto: `echo "Error";` por esto: **`echo "Error: ".$db->error;`**  y nos cuentas qué error muestra.

Comment: Me muestra esto :/   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 22

Comment: Disculpen me marcaba eso por la falta de un ; jeje. Ahora la actualizo, trato de insertar el archivo y sigue sin decirme nada }

Comment: Propongo que uses un código que indique en todo momento cuál es el error, ya que tu actual código pasa por alto demasiadas situaciones, por tanto es imposible saber lo que ocurre. Cuando programes, tienes que prever todas las posibles situaciones y emitir mensajes de lo que ocurre ante posibles fallos. Un código mudo en ciertos posibles  `else` hace que pierdas horas y horas tratando de *adivinar*  por qué no funciona como esperas. Prueba esto y dinos qué pasa ahora, lo pongo en dos partes porque en una no cabe:

Comment: `include_once 'conectar.php'; if (isset($_POST['subir'])) { $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name']; $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type']; $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size']; $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']; $destino = "pdf/" . $nombre; if ($nombre != "") { if (copy($ruta, $destino)) { `

Comment: `$titulo= $_POST['titulo']; $descri= $_POST['descripcion']; $db=new Conect_MySql(); $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_documentos(titulo,descripcion,tamanio,tipo,nombre_archivo) VALUES('$titulo','$descripcion','$tamanio','$tipo','$nombre')"; $query = $db->execute($sql); if($query){ echo "Se guardo correctamente"; } else { echo "Error SQL: ".$db->error; } } else { echo "Error en el copy"; } }else{ echo "Error nombre"; } }else{ echo "No hay POST"; }`

Comment: Disculpa :( apenas incursiono en esto y tengo muchas fallas aún :(, lo que me dice ahora es "No hay POST"

Comment: Entonces esto no se cumple: `if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {` ... debes revisar lo que estás enviando a ese archivo, vía un formulario posiblemente, y si lo estás enviando al archivo correcto.

Comment: Gracias!, en verdad eres muy amable, y si, de ahora en adelante implementaré esa parte, porque si no se ni por donde empezar a buscar para reparar los errores, mil gracias en verdad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He añadido los trozos de código que necesitaba para hacer que funcionara y he corregido algunas cosillas, como crear el directorio pdf si no existiera, la variable descri que habías llamado de dos formas distintas y el execute que te comentaba A.Cedano. Pruébalo y me dices qué tal.

```
<?php
//include_once 'conectar.php';
class Conect_MySql{
    function __construct(){
        $this->conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['subir'])){
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "pdf/" . $nombre;
    if(!glob('pdf')) mkdir('pdf');
    if ($nombre != "") {
        if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
            $titulo= $_POST['titulo'];
            $descripcion= $_POST['descripcion'];
            $db=new Conect_MySql();
            $sql = "
                INSERT INTO tbl_documentos(titulo,descripcion,tamanio,tipo,nombre_archivo)
                    VALUES('$titulo','$descripcion','$tamanio','$tipo','$nombre')
            ";
            $query = $db->conn->query($sql);
            if($query){
                echo "Se guardo correctamente";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="titulo">
<input type="text" name="descripcion" placeholder="descripcion">
<input type="file" name="archivo">
<input type="hidden" name="subir" value="1">
<button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Mil gracias David, me funcionó de maravilla, igual la parte del formulario si la tenía, pero no la postee, mil gracias por tu ayuda, igual aun trato de ver que me faltaba y aprender de ese errorcillo, ustedes son muy amables :)

Comment: De nada Paloma, me alegra haberte ayudado. Sólo eran un par de cosillas. Intenta adjuntar todo lo que pueda ser necesario para reproducir tu problema: formularios, tablas, datos... cuanto más fácil nos lo pongas, más fácil será ayudarte. Ah, ¡y vota en positivo todo lo que te guste! :)